# VBA - Parsing CSV function, getting output of function

Tags: function, vba, parsing, csv

I have a code (please see below) to parse a csv file. After the function  I want to use that data, but I'm not sure what is th ouput of the function or how can I use it? Basically the csv has a column of number which I want to copy in my main sheet, but after the function how can I copy/paste the data within the sub enviroment?

Many thanks!

```
Function ParsefileAsTable(ByVal sNomFichier As String) As Variant
Dim Chaine As String
Dim Ar() As String
Dim var As Variant
Dim nblignes As Long
Dim nbcol As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
Dim NumFichier As Integer
Dim Separateur As String * 1

    Separateur = ","
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Close
    NumFichier = FreeFile

    iRow = 0
    Open sNomFichier For Input As #NumFichier

    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #NumFichier, Chaine
        nblignes = nblignes + 1
        Ar = Split(Chaine, Separateur)
        nbcol = UBound(Ar) + 1
    Loop
    Close #NumFichier

ReDim var(1 To nblignes, 1 To nbcol)

iRow = 0
    Open sNomFichier For Input As #NumFichier
        Do While Not EOF(NumFichier)
                iCol = 1: iRow = iRow + 1
                Line Input #NumFichier, Chaine
                Ar = Split(Chaine, Separateur)
                For i = LBound(Ar) To UBound(Ar)
                    If Not iCol > nbcol Then
                        var(iRow, iCol) = Ar(i)
                        iCol = iCol + 1
                    End If
                Next
        Loop
    Close #NumFichier

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

ParsefileAsTable = var

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of the function is type Variant, as defined by the function itself.

```
Function ParsefileAsTable(ByVal sNomFichier As String) As Variant
```

The return value of the function is the variable `var`, as assigned before `End Function`:

```
ParsefileAsTable = var
```

You can put this in to a worksheet like this, from the calling subroutine (it is generally advisable to use functions only to return values, not to manipulate sheet objects):

```
Dim var as Variant
var = ParseFileAsTable("C:\mon_fichier.txt")

Range("A1").Resize(UBound(var, 1), UBound(var, 2)).Value = _
    var
```

**EDIT** I made a revision to the above line to deal with arrays based 1 (normally they are 0)...

The error you received is because `var` was not a variable defined in the calling procedure, so the revision above instantiates that variable, and then assigns the function's return value.  We then use the `var` to determine the size of the range (using the `Resize`) method, and print the array to that range.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply! However when I write that it says type mismatch? Can you explain a bit more the last bit of code? Basically I want to copy that data into a column in the main excel sheet

Comment: See my revision & explanation.  It was an error in my code, but the revision I think should work for you.

Comment: That's much better thanks! However after the two columns are changed a third column is also change weirdly, but only one, do you know why this is happening? I'm choosing D3 in range and both columns D are E are changed but also F

Comment: And the last question, there is a cell with the date, each file for the parse function has a different date, do I want the code to read the cell with the date and add the in the string of the file, is it possible to do this? Thanks!

Comment: This should only change two columns. Did you forget to make some revision (previously it was `UBound(var, 2) + 1`, remove the `+1`)?

Comment: Your last question, yes it is possible. There are hundreds of answers here about how to iterate a range of cells.  I'm afraid I will not answer that at this point, because it is not part of your original question, and the answer is going to be more complicated (i.e., where to output the table data from multiple files, etc. -- in the same sheet, or in a new sheet, in a new file?? Etc.).  Please mark this answer accepted if it solves the immediate problem.  If you have further questions implementing the loop over your function, please ask them as a *new* question.

Comment: Yes I did remove the +1

Comment: Ok, I put -1 instead but the number appear as "53, etc, why like this?

Comment: and the other question is not about iteration, it's just one file at a time, I just need a way of copying the date into the string of the file

Comment: Sorry it's not another column, it is this: forcexample, 53,000 is written as "53          000", why like this?

Comment: For the date, I just need to write a string like this: "thisfile"&"mydate"&".csv", is this possible? I know in matlab it is

Comment: "but the number appear as "53, etc, why like this? " **I do not understand what you are asking.**

Comment: "Sorry it's not another column, it is this: forcexample, 53,000 is written as "53 000","  **I do not understand what this question is asking**.

Comment: "For the date, I just need to write a string like ..."  Yes, this is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not going to answer the questions about the number "53", or "53,000" or "53 000" . Tehse are entirely out of scope from your original question. Please appreciate that I am helping you for free, and the never-ending follow-up questions suggest that you do not understand any of what you are doing.  You need to learn this yourself.